# Unexpected behaviour in Ruby for "puts {}.class"

Tags: ruby

```
puts {}.class

#=> NilClass 

puts "".class
String
#=> nil 

puts [].class
Array
#=> nil
```

Why is `puts {}.class` not showing `Hash` as output and then `nil` like the others?

Comment: Another way to see `puts {}.class` is `puts do ; end.class`

Comment: Maybe parenthesis will help `puts(){} #=> nil`, `nil.class #=> NilClass`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a couple things to understand:

1. whenever a hash is the first argument to a method being called, you need to use parenthesis or remove the braces, otherwise ruby thinks it's a block. So `puts { foo: "bar" }` raises a syntax error, but `puts foo: "bar"`, `puts(foo: "bar")`, or `puts({foo: "bar"})` work fine.
2. every method can be called with a block, however only some methods actually call the block. You can test it for yourself - `puts(1) { raise }` just outputs the number, and doesn't raise an error. `puts { 1 }` prints nothing, because the block isn't called.
3. The `puts` method always returns nil. So when you say `puts {}.class`, that's basically the same as `puts.class`, which is NilClass

Answer (score 21):

`puts {}` is interpreted as `puts` method call with empty block passed into it, hence the empty result. `puts({}.class)` works as you expect.

Comment: `puts` method always returns `nil`. Passing block, has no effect to it. So return value is `nil`.